# How to return int array from Java to JNI

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I have to call a Java method from JNI. This Java method returns int array (int[] simpleMethod()). How to call this from JNI to get the array as a return value? 
I know how to do this when method returns void/String/int/etc but couldn't find anything with arrays.
I have some ideas how to work around this but maybe there is simple answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `CallObjectMethod`.  For example:

```
jmethodID myMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(myClass, "myMethod", "()[I");
jintArray retval = (jintArray) (*env)->CallObjectMethod(myObject, myMethod);
```